# Looping through a list of SQL data in VisualBasic.NET

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, foreach

I'm trying (using SQL and VB.Net) to get a list of dates and strings (representing a film name) using a SELECT command, and then look through each of the 'dates' in the list, one after the other. Like a 'FOR EACH' loop.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this, but here's what I have so far:

> ```
>     Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=ApplicationData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
>     Con.Open() 'Open the connection
>     Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT fDateAdded, fName FROM Films", Con)
>
>     Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
>     Dim Rdr As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
>     Dim schemaTable As DataTable = Rdr.GetSchemaTable()
>
>     Dim row As DataRow
>     Dim column As DataColumn
>
>     For Each row In schemaTable.Rows
>         For Each column In schemaTable.Columns
>             ' WHAT TO DO HERE?
>         Next
>     Next
> ```

How can I go about achieving my goal?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do exactly. Looks like you want to go through each column and check if its the date column. You don't need to do that. The select statement shows that the first column will be date so you can look up row item directly. If the date matches your criteria then you can also access the other row item (fName) and do what you need. If its doesn't then just skip to next row

Comment: Fantastic! How could I do this in VB.net code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-next loop should be something like this...

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
    If row.Item("fDateAdded") = *your match criteria* Then
        *Do something - you can utilies* row.Item("fName") *if you need*
    End if
Next row
```

The match criteria can of course be anything < <= > >= or a combination to give you a range etc.

Hope that helps.